# Is it good practice to store items retrieved from a web service as Core Data objects?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've heard of iOS developers retrieving items from a RESTful web service and storing them as Core Data objects right away. I can see why that may be useful if you want to save or cache these items so the user can see them later (e.g. Facebook feed), but are there any other reasons to do so? I have items in my web service that are invalid within an hour, so caching is out of the question. If it's a good practice to do so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, there are 2 reasons to stock datas in local:

- Better UX: first, show old contents, then do an update in background for example, then update your application UI when new contents are availables.
- Work offline whenever online mode is impossible.

Even if your items are invalid within an hour, if you do not cache items in local, your application has to call to webservice to retrieve these items, and it takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Caching almost never hurts and CoreData is a very nice way to cache data which comes in as a pile of similar records.

I am one of those devs you mentioned who store almost anything using CoreData. Because I do, a lot of useful code and selfmade frameworks has summed up over time which make working with CoreData and RESTful apis a breeze. And if connecting an api to CoreData is just a matter of a few lines of code, there really isn't any reason not to.

While I cannot share my libraries, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/), which does pretty much the same - mapping a RESTful api to CoreData. And if you're not used to CoreData yet, fear not. It is a very powerful tool and getting used to it is definitely worth the while!